# How to save files in my server with ScriptCam plugin

Tags: jquery, video-streaming, video-recording

I want the users of my website to stream video in the website and preview it.
then they can click save and the file is saved in the website's server. I found this [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/ScriptCam/)

It seem to work fine, but the problem is that after it makes the file conversion it gives me a link to download the file whis supposedely is kept in ScriptCam's own server. I also noticed that their server URL is pre appended to the "fileName" variable. i don't know where it's coming from.

Any help is welcome,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

Actually You can save the video file in your server. In that case you have to go to the code from where the link is generated. Then send the video url to a php page via ajax `$.post` method.Then in the php page write a php "copy" function. See the code below :-

First go to the `fileReady()` in the index.php page to get the video url:-

```
function fileReady(fileName) {
    $('#recorder').hide();              
    $('#message').html('This file is now dowloadable for five minutes over 
                <a href='+fileName+'>here</a>.');
    var x=fileName;

    if (x != null){
    $.post('ack.php', {x: x}, function(){
        //successful ajax request
    }).error(function(){
        alert('error... ohh no!');
    });

}

var fileNameNoExtension=fileName.replace(".mp4", "");
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        width:320,
        height:240,
        file: fileName,
        image: fileNameNoExtension+"_0000.jpg"
    });

    $('#mediaplayer').show();
}
```

the create a php page as I have created as ack.php. then write the following code:-
**ack.php**

```
$val=$_POST['x'];

$file = $val; 
$newfile = 'video/output.mp4'; 

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) { 
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n"; 
}
```

This works fine but the problem is that the video quality is not very good. If anyone can give me solution that how can I increase the video quality in scriptcam then that will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,  I found out I had to register and set up the ftp options and also  allow incoming connections on my server.