# Save webcam recording from scriptcam

Tags: php, jquery, webcam, scriptcam

I'm looking for a solution similar to the one offered here (my problem is the same): [How to save files in my server with ScriptCam plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791850/how-to-save-files-in-my-server-with-scriptcam-plugin)

unfortunately, that one doesn't work for me.
I have a scriptcam plugin on my website. The recorded videos should be sent to my ftp folder but it isn't working (although the .txt testfile does work). Scriptcam support is apparently non-existent..

so I thought it must be feasible to automatically capture the video from the generated link by scriptcam, but I'm not sure how. My PHP is very basic, and ironically, my php course is starting next week Wednesday, two days after the site (http://www.trainemotionmanagement.com) has to go live..

Any ideas?

The scriptcam 'recording ready' function looks like this:

```
function fileReady(fileName) {
            $('#recorder').hide();
            fileName2=fileName.replace('mp4','gif');
            $('#message').html('The MP4 file is now dowloadable for five minutes over <a href="'+fileName+'">here</a>. The animated GIF can be downloaded <a href="'+fileName2+'">here</a>.');
            var fileNameNoExtension=fileName.replace(".mp4", "");
            jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
                width:320,
                height:240,
                file: fileName,
                image: fileNameNoExtension+'_0000.jpg',
                tracks: [{ 
                    file: fileNameNoExtension+'.vtt', 
                    kind: 'thumbnails'
                }]
            });
            $('#mediaplayer').show();
        }
```

EDIT: ISSUE RESOLVED. HOW? No idea, it just started working all of a sudden..

Answer (score 0):

If the test .txt file is stored in your ftp then it means ftp connection and other settings are fine.
From your description of the problem it seems you may not have used the write js codes to make the whole thing work.

There is a dome on scriptcam website which perfectly worked for me.
http://www.scriptcam.com/demo_2.cfm

This should work for you also.

Comment: Nope.. I've been scouring the internet and apparently it happens to a number of people.

Answer (score 0):

function fileReady(fileName) {
           $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  data:{"file_name":fileName},
                  url: URL,
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  success: function(responseXml) {
                    $('#message').html('Video created successfully..');

`}

            });   

    }`

In server side

get the filename parameter,(where filename will be url for mp4 file)

if you are using php

file_put_contents("saving_filename", fopen(filename, 'r'));

and save.

please note that scriptcam will delete this file form their server after  5 minutes. So we need to copy the file using this method or need to setup the ftp server details.

enjoy !!!