# How to save files in my local directory using ScriptCam?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video-streaming, video-recording

I've tried to follow the steps of www.scriptcam.com and [How to save files in my server with ScriptCam plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791850/how-to-save-files-in-my-server-with-scriptcam-plugin).
the script like below :

```js
function fileReady(fileName) {
    $('#recorder').hide();              
    $('#message').html('This file is now dowloadable for five minutes over 
                <a href='+fileName+'>here</a>.');
    var x=fileName;

    if (x != null){
    $.post('ack.php', {x: x}, function(){
        //successful ajax request
    }).error(function(){
        alert('error... ohh no!');
    });

}

var fileNameNoExtension=fileName.replace(".mp4", "");
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
    width:320,
    height:240,
    file: fileName,
    image: fileNameNoExtension+"_0000.jpg"
});

$('#mediaplayer').show();
}
```

In my ack.php script like below :

```js
ack.php
$val=$_POST['x'];

$file = $val; 
$newfile = 'video/output.mp4'; 

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) { 
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n"; 
}
```

but the files are not stored in my folder 'video', what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

1.keep your ack.php and video folder in same folder.
2.see that you have given (read/write files)permissions to video folder 
3.if not then you can give it by going to its properties
4. and then make a try 
5. i have done same on my server and got success.